# How do I find the Thevenin Voltage?

Tags: voltage, thevenin, norton

I have this problem that I need to study up for my electronics reexam.

I do not know how I got the Vc/5 , probably from a YT guide I saw at that time.

Please help me if you can, because I cannot understand electronics but I need to pass this for my studies.

If you need me to clarify something, due to my bad handwriting just

[image: My problem:]

Comment: What does this mean and how does it relate to the question: *I do not know how I got the Vc/5 , probably from a YT guide I saw at that time.*

Comment: Check your calculation of \$I_1\$, pay attention to the directions!

Comment: So in my calculations I have (Vc-60)/30-2A-Vc/5 and I dont know how I got that. I am also confused myself how I got most of this. I am completely lost in this subject.

To better understand the subject I watched a video from The organic chemistry teacher and he used Vc/5 so I guess that were I took it from, but I dont know, since I dont know what I am even doing.

Comment: @uriyabsc can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: By you definition of the direction of \$I_1\$, \$I_1 = \frac{60-V_C}{30}\$.

Comment: Also, how did you conclude that \$I_3=V_C/5\$? It makes no sense. I advise you to rely on your own calculations rather than those of your peers, professors and people on Youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is (way) more complicated than this one. Also, this method will check your work.

Well, we are trying the analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyrt1c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_5
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle0-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

We also know that \$\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2=\text{V}_\text{i}\$.

Now, we can set up a Mathematica code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == Ia + I2, I2 == I3 + I4, I5 == I3 + I4, I1 == Ia + I5, 
   I1 == (V1 - V3)/R1, I1 == (0 - V2)/R2, I3 == V3/R3, I4 == V3/R4, 
   V1 - V2 == Vi}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, V1, V2, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (Ia R3 R4 + (R3 + R4) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  I2 -> ((R3 + R4) (-Ia (R1 + R2) + 
      Vi))/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  I3 -> (R4 (-Ia (R1 + R2) + Vi))/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  I4 -> (R3 (-Ia (R1 + R2) + Vi))/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  I5 -> ((R3 + R4) (-Ia (R1 + R2) + 
      Vi))/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  V1 -> (-Ia R2 R3 R4 + (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) Vi)/((R1 + 
       R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  V2 -> -((R2 (Ia R3 R4 + (R3 + R4) Vi))/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + 
        R3) R4)), 
  V3 -> (R3 R4 (-Ia (R1 + R2) + 
      Vi))/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4)}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_3\$ and letting \$\text{R}_4\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{I}_\text{a}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\tag3$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_4\$ and letting \$\text{R}_4\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}-\text{I}_\text{a}\tag4$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R3 R4 (-Ia (R1 + R2) + 
     Vi))/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), R4 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=(R3 (-Ia (R1 + R2) + Vi))/(R1 + R2 + R3)

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R3 (-Ia (R1 + R2) + Vi))/((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4), 
  R4 -> 0]]

Out[3]=-Ia + Vi/(R1 + R2)

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=((R1 + R2) R3)/(R1 + R2 + R3)
```

Using your values, we find:

$$\text{V}_\text{th}=-24\space\text{V}\space\wedge\space\text{I}_\text{th}=-1\space\text{A}\space\wedge\space\text{R}_\text{th}=24\space\Omega\tag6$$

Comment: seems to make sense tho I dont fully understand the rules at play here.

And is the I1=0-V2/R2 just a typo and should be I2 or do we really have 2 equations for I1?

Comment: @FlyCaptain No it is not a typo. The current \$\text{I}_1\$ is flowing through \$\text{R}_1\$ and \$\text{R}_2\$.

Answer (score 2):

> *How do I find the Thevenin Voltage?*

I think solving it by inspection is a more fool-proof way: -

[image]

Comment: You get the 80V from ohms law by use of V=I*R correct? 
And why do you put the 80v source in series to the 40ohm and not in parallel?

Comment: @FlyCaptain its how you convert a current source with a parallel resistor to a voltage source and series resistor. It's called [source transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_transformation) <-- probably the most important conversion tool in your armoury.

Comment: It also makes use of [Thevenin equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem)

Comment: Great answer, it's much better than brute-forcing your way through a system of equations with the use of Mathematica. One thing though, I'd appreciate if you moved the text from the images to actual text, for better accessibility.